# Count how many rows are for a value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table that looks like this:

```
[ContractId]     [ContractDate] [SnapshotTimeId]    [DaysPastDue] [Exposure]

Int(not unique)  Datetime       Int(format20160431) Int           Int
```

The table is sorted by ContractId, ContractDate.

Now, I would like to add a 6th column, let's call it Unique, which has value 1 for the first ContractId value then adds 1 until it bumps across the next ContractId. Basically, I want to know how many rows I have for each ContractId and put the values, incrementally, in a column.

Edit: I want the output to look like this

```
>DocumentId ContractDate    SnapshottimeId  DPD Exposure Unique
>1          31-Aug-15       31-Aug-15       0   500      1
>1          31-Aug-15       30-Sep-15       5   450      2
>1          31-Aug-15       31-Oct-15       35  450      3
>1          31-Aug-15       30-Nov-15       7   350      4
>1          31-Aug-15       31-Dec-15       37  350      5
>1          31-Aug-15       31-Jan-16       67  340      6
>2          31-Aug-15       30-Jun-14       3   800      1
>2          31-Aug-15       31-Jul-14       15  760      2
>2          31-Aug-15       31-Aug-14       45  750      3
>2          31-Aug-15       30-Sep-14       75  750      4
>2          31-Aug-15       31-Oct-14       0   630      5
>2          31-Aug-15       30-Nov-14       15  590      6
>2          31-Aug-15       31-Dec-14       45  580      7
```

Comment: Can you show some sample input and expected output

Comment: Provide some sample data

Comment: When you say "add a 6th column" do you mean physically store it in the database, or create that value when you `select` data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by contractid order by contractdate) as seqnum
from t;
```

This will put an incremental value, which is what I think you are describing.

If you just want the count of rows for each contract in each row, then use:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by contractid) as cnt
from t;
```

This would put "6" in each row, if there are six rows for a the contract.

Comment: Thanks! row_number is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

> which has value 1 for the first ContractId value then adds 1 until it bumps across the next ContractId

RowNumber will do the trick

```
select *,
Row_number() over (partition by contractid order by contractid) as countt
from
table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the line number in your table, just use this :

```
Select ContractId, 
    ContractDate, 
    SnapshotTimeId, 
    DaysPastDue, 
    Exposure, 
    row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ContractId] asc) AS Row 
From YourTable
```